# Get last 'Text' Data from system clipboard outside current page

Tags: javascript, clipboard

So far, all the answers are concentrated in capturing the events inside the webpage. But, is it possible  to retrieve the last 'text' data in the clipboard using javascript?

What I want to do is that when the user click a textarea, it automatically changes its value to the last copied element from the system clipboard (from any page or other application).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, there is no simple way to do this. You can use flash hacks (I don't know them personally) to get access to the clipboard whenever you want, but otherwise, you're limited to accessing the user's clipboard (in your case, to read what is on it) during system clipboard events (triggered by keyboard shortcuts or from the browser's menus).

In IE, you can access the clipboard whenever you want using the following code:

```
window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
```

But if it isn't during a system clipboard event, the user will be prompted as to whether or not they want to grant you access.

You can get a workaround in Chrome by using a chrome extension that grants your site/app [clipboard permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions). From there you can just force a paste event using the following code.

```
window.execCommand('paste');
```

This should cause whatever is on the clipboard to be pasted (since your text area is selected, it should paste into your text area).

That's probably as far as you'll be able to get, though, unless you figure out a way to get flash to do it for you ([ZeroClipboard](http://zeroclipboard.org/) seems like a promising option).

If you're interested in some more details, I wrote a technical [blog post](https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2014/12/02/definitive-guide-copying-pasting-javascript/) on this subject after doing extensive work on this at Lucidchart (where I work).

Comment: Thanks for this complete answer. I was afraid that it was the case.